# Python - TCP Server

Tags: python, tcp, raspbian, recv

I'm new in python.
I've found a simple TCP Server's code and it works. 
The problem is: i'm not able to make a if...elif...else works.
I think it's a mistake of value's type.

Here's my code (the program always do the else part):

```
while 1:
    data = clientsocket.recv(1024)
    tokens = data.split(' ',1)
    command = tokens[0]
    if not command:
        break
    else:
        if command == 1:
            try:
                camera.start_preview()
                time.sleep(10)
                camera.stop_preview()
            finally:
                camera.close()
        elif command == 2:
            print "Something"
        elif command == 3:
            print "something else"
        else:
            print data
            print tokens[0]
            print command
clientsocket.close()
```

It give me the result of the last else which is :

```
2

2

2
```

Or the number I send. Thanks in advance for your responses !

Comment: try `command = int(tokens[0])` since the data received is a `string` and not `int`

Comment: @SebastienVoisard print out the value of `data` and finally of `command`, it will give you the answer. Even better, try to debug the code (using pdb or ipdb), and inspect the changes step by step). See http://pymotw.com/2/pdb/

Comment: You were right, the type was not the same, thanks, it works now !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`command` is a string, not an integer; you are comparing:

```
>>> '2' == 2
False
```

Instead, use:

```
...
tokens = data.split(' ', 1)
try:
    command = int(tokens[0])
except ValueError:
    break

if command == 1:
    ...
```